# How can I use the function std::min() to calculate the minimum?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I want to use `std::min()`, but it shows an error. I included the  library:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    result[i] = std::min({sonarRange[i], sonarRange2[i], sonarRange3[i]});
}
```

Comment: Dod you have `#include <algorithm>` in your code?  Please edit your question with a [mre].

Comment: Include the error message in your question. Do not post images of your code, post your code.

Comment: What is the error you got?

Comment: syntax error:'{'

Comment: Are you compiling using C++11 or newer?

Comment: I use visual studio 2015

Comment: @MohammadF that is not what Nathan asked.  Are you compiling in C++11 mode?  `std::min()` accepts a `std::initializer_list` of values only in C++11 and later, but [according to this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c111417-features-in-vs-2015-rtm/), I don't think VS2015 supported that use of `std::min()` yet.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to pass a `std::initializer_list` to `std::min()`, but according to [C++11/14/17 Features In VS 2015 RTM](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c111417-features-in-vs-2015-rtm/), I don't think Visual Studio 2015 supported that use of `std::min()` yet.  You can alternatively put the 3 values into an `int[3]` array instead and use `std::min_element()` to find the minimum:

```cpp
for(size_t i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    int ranges[] = {sonarRange[i], sonarRange2[i], sonarRange3[i]};
    result[i] = *std::min_element(std::begin(ranges), std::end(ranges));
}
```